# Android Heap Massage Needed

Tags: java, android, memory, heap-memory

I am trying to load a saved game on my app. Problem is, I keep getting the following problem:

```
 06-01 00:42:36.123: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(10297): Heap Massage needed (5107596-byte    
   external allocation too big)

 06-01 00:42:36.123: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(10297): -->Full GC (don't collect 
       SoftReferences)

 06-01 00:42:36.163: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(10297): -->Heap Massage was successful...
```

I think I know why. The current game (that I want to be deleted and forgotten) is still retaining memory. I want to "unblock" this memory, so is there any way I can do a "heap dump" (quotes are used as I am a noob and am probably using the wrong technical words)?

Comment: Do you have a global map of textures (or anything I guess) loaded somewhere?  If so, you probably want to use WeakReferences in that map...

Comment: I don't have anything like that. I have a surfaceview with some biggish bitmaps.

Answer (score 2):

Once you eliminate all references to your current game data (by setting all relevant variables, hash entries, etc., to `null`), you can call `System.gc()` (or `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()`) to suggest to the JVM that this would be a good time for a garbage collection. Note, however, that you cannot *force* a garbage collection this way.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Calling Gerbage Collection doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Sometimes it is hard to track down all references to data that needs to be freed. As long as there is a single live reference, the data will not be reclaimed by the GC. The article [Avoiding Memory Leaks](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) covers a number of issues specific to Android.